# c program to display function for linked list

Tags: c

I am new at C programming and I am trying to write a display method for a linked list. My problem is that there should be priority for characters. I mean it should be look like : P1 P2 P3 S5 S9 S20 A2 A6 A4. My code works but I do not know how to order characters like that. Here is my code:

```
    struct node {
    int pages;
    char userType;
    struct node *next;
};

struct node *first= NULL;
struct node *temp=NULL;

void enqueue(char ch, int pr){
    struct node *np, *temp, *prev;
    int found;

    np= (struct node *)malloc(sizeof(struct node));
    np->userType= ch;
    np->pages= pr;
    np->next= NULL;
    if(first == NULL){
        first=np;
        return;
    }

    temp= first;
    found=0;

    while((temp != NULL) && (!found)){
        if(temp->pages < pr){
            prev= temp;
            temp= temp->next;
        }else{
            found=1;
        }
    }

    if(prev == NULL){
        np->next= first;
        first= np;
    }else{
        prev->next=np;
        np->next=temp;
    }

}

void display(){
    struct node *np;
    np= first;
    while (np != NULL){
        printf("%d", np->pages);
        np= np->next;
    }
}


main(){
    srand(time(NULL));
    int p,d,i;
    char c;
    for(i=0; i<50; i++){
        p=1+(rand()%20);
        d=rand()%3;
        switch(d){
            case 0: c= 'P'; break;
            case 1: c= 'A'; break;
            case 2: c= 's'; break;
        }

        enqueue(c,p);
    }

    display();
}
```

Can you offer any solution? Thanx in advance

Comment: There's obviously nothing wrong with your `display` function. Look at the `enqueue` function instead. And you shouldn't be using global variables.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is when inserting a node, in the `enqueue()` function:

Change:

```
   struct node *np, *temp, *prev;
```

To:

```
   struct node *np, *temp, *prev=NULL;
```

---

Spoiler code **[here](http://www.mahonri.info/SO/23920599_c-program-to-display-function-for-linked-list.c)**.